# How to set selected in <option>?

Tags: html

Is it possible to set `selected` as some function?

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo" selected="myFunc()">Volvo</option> <!-- example -->
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I want to set selected where it's match with the day I send just like Monday, Tuesday etc.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `selected="myFunc()"` is wrong because `selected`is an attribute not event handler instead you can use `onchange="myFunc()"` event.. simply use `selected` BTW: elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

The only value the `selected` attribute can have is `selected`.

If you want to modify the selected option with JavaScript, then put it in a `<script>` element after the `<select>`, find the `<select>` through the DOM and then change it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this html code instead:

```
<select onchange="func(this.value)">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and this js:

```
function func(value) {
  if (value == "volvo") {
    myFunc();
  }
}
```

the javascript checks wich value is selected and runs a function when the selected value is "volvo"

Comment: This function will execute when click list, am I right? But if I dont click the list. It will always return the first.